# MPC on boolean circuits

Tags: multiparty-computation

I am reading about Yao's and GMW protocols and was wondering if there is any perfectly secure MPC protocol in the semi-honest setting, where the underlying circuit is a Boolean circuit (eg. n=3 and t=1)?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily embed a Boolean circuit into the field $GF[2^k]$ for any $k$. Once you have done this embedding, you can then run any perfectly secure protocol. However, note that perfect security requires $t<n/3$ and so a minimum of 4 parties (with 1 corruption). For $n=3$ and $t=1$, it is possible to get statistical security.

Note that for the specific case of $n=3$ and $t=1$ you can also use a dedicated for Boolean circuits. For semi-honest adversaries, one example is [High-Throughput Semi-Honest Secure Three-Party Computation with an Honest Majority](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/768.pdf).